# Is it possible to specify why you’re asking for a users location?

Tags: html

I’m using the coordinates JS api and whenever I access the page an alert window pops up asking to approve to use the location info.

Is it possible to specify in that alert that “this approval will be used for XYZ”?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you just put a paragraph on the site explaining why

Comment: Show some code so we can help you better

Comment: @Huangism has a valid advice: just render the message on the page. I suppose that you're looking for a browser notification, but those are "browser specific" and maybe wouldn't work on any specific scenario.

Comment: There's no any method or property of object described in interface spec: https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. A nice way to handle this is following the pattern that some native apps do. You can show a popup saying that you're going to request location services. The user can say "okay" and then you prompt them with the request. If they say "no" you just don't prompt them.

Something like this:

```
if (confirm("We're going to ask you for you location in order to show the coffee shops near you. Please accept the request.")) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((location) => {
    // Do location stuff
  });
}
```